# React.js : Proxy that I set in package.json does not work in made by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, proxy

```
"proxy": {
  "/auth/google": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5001"
  },
  "/api/user": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5001"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem , I should have set proxy in webpack.config.js file

```
devServer: {
 historyApiFallback:true,
 proxy:{
        "/api/user":"http://localhost:5001"
    }
}
```